# What do the various MaaS node statuses mean?

Tags: maas

I'm interested in some more info on the different node state's

The below link list some of the possible node status

- http://people.canonical.com/~gavin/docs/lp:maas/enum.html#maasserver.models.NODE_STATUS

So from my understanding the PXE enlist gives you a declared node, then before you can use the node with juju you need to Accept & Commission, this gives you a commissioning state then after that the node become ready.

My question is what is happening in the commissioning state ?

Does it need to boot the node?

Does it install the OS ?

And do I need to bootstrap juju for the nodes to become ready or will successful commissioning move the node state to ready ?

Answer (score 1):

Commissioning boots the node up using an ephemeral image and runs a
commissioning script.

The script is basically doing a smoke test, and calls
back to the maas server with an API request that tells it commissioning
succeeded (or failed) which makes maas move the node to READY or FAILED_TESTS.

An OS is not installed at that stage, only doing a juju bootstrap does this
(when it's allocated).

We aim to speed things up in the future by using squashfs to skip the lengthy
installation time.